# How to write a multiline default value in giter8?

Tags: sbt, giter8

All parameters and their default values are fined in the `default.properties` file.

How can you have a parameter with a value that spans over multiple lines?

Example that works:

```
hello = world
```

Example that doesn't work

```
hello = one 
two
```

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters can be written in the standard Java configuration style. So in the example above:

```
hello = one\ 
        two
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when passing a multiline parameter to the g8 command line

Comment: Ben, could be a bash issue. If you paste your command I may be able to help.

Comment: I believe its a regex issue within Giter8, have created a PR https://github.com/foundweekends/giter8/pull/367

Comment: it doesnt seem to work for me, in the `description` field, to have a several paragraph introduction